# MySQL MIN() function returns only one record

Tags: mysql, sql, select, min

I have a dataset as per:

```
+----+---------------+-------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | ip            | port  | point_count | create_time         |
+----+---------------+-------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 192.168.20.28 | 10000 |           0 | 2013-03-29 14:29:14 |
|  2 | 0.0.0.0       | 10000 |           0 | 2013-03-29 14:29:32 |
|  3 | 0.0.0.1       | 11111 |           2 | 2013-03-29 14:29:38 |
|  4 | 0.0.0.5       | 11112 |           3 | 2013-03-29 14:29:44 |
+----+---------------+-------+-------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I use mysql's `MIN()` function to fetch records as per:

```
mysql> SELECT s.id, s.ip, s.port, MIN(s.point_count) FROM origin_server s;
+----+---------------+-------+--------------------+
| id | ip            | port  | MIN(s.point_count) |
+----+---------------+-------+--------------------+
|  1 | 192.168.20.28 | 10000 |                  0 |
+----+---------------+-------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Obviously, there are two rows have the same value for column point_count , but it returned me only one record. I just wanna confirm if this situation is correct. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What value are you wanting in the min column? The overall min, or the min for each ip/port?

Comment: I just want only one record that has the minimum point_count :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you are getting only one record is because `MIN()` is an aggregate function which return one record for every group. Since you have not specify a `GROUP BY` clause, the result is normal which gives you only one record.

You can use a subquery to get the minimum value of `point_count` and equate it to the outer query's  `point_count`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    origin_server 
WHERE   point_count = (SELECT MIN(point_count) FROM origin_server)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dc94/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════════════╦═══════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID ║      IP       ║ PORT  ║ POINT_COUNT ║     CREATE_TIME     ║
╠════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ 192.168.20.28 ║ 10000 ║           0 ║ 2013-03-29 14:29:14 ║
║  2 ║ 0.0.0.0       ║ 10000 ║           0 ║ 2013-03-29 14:29:32 ║
╚════╩═══════════════╩═══════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: +1 You edited your question as per my request for info around _why_ and _how_ that query worked at all, just as I typed it ;-)  So can you explain how mySql _chooses_ which of the two (or more) rows to return as its "group", when no `GROUP BY` is specified? I presume that's just the first row returned, based on clustered index?

Comment: @Sepster you cannot really determine the record that will be selected. It's stated on the manual (*I'm searching for the link*).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **it is correct that only one record is returned**: the other values returned are "ill-defined" and cannot be reliably viewed as part of a aggregate!

*If an aggregate function is used then it effectively treats the entire query as a single group* (barring any other defined grouping). To get *well-defined* behavior then all the columns in the select list must be aggregates or must be mentioned in a GROUP BY clause.

Using `SELECT s.ip, MIN(s.point_count) FROM origin_server s GROUP by s.ip` would return 4 records (with the `MIN` being applied *per group*), because it defines a different grouping.

Using `SELECT MIN(s.point_count) FROM origin_server s` would return only the minimum point_count (over the entire query), which is logically correct and is the only information from the original query that is guaranteed. When viewing it as such, it makes sense that only a single record is returned.

Comment: +1.  But: "it could have been _any_ of the other values returned".  While this is true in the context of the OPs question, is this _strictly_ true in general?  eg perhaps it could be the first record found, based on eg clustered index? or is it _genuinely_ undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Sepster It depends upon the *exact query plan* and *implementation of such* .. or "ill-defined" in my book. That is, for a given query [plan] and database it is likely consistent - add a different index and then it could be a different query plan entirely.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, agree that's "ill-defined".  I'd call it "undefined for all practical purposes".  I come from an MSSQL background, where aggregation functions cannot be used within a select containing non-aggregated results, unless each non-aggregated column is also included explicitly in a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Sepster Yes, I come from MSSQL and very much prefer the strictness in this aspect. I used "ill-define" here (in quotes) because I'm not technically certain how it is defined (or not) .. I should probably try to track down some better wording or an authoritative resource.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what you want, but try this:

```
select
   ip,
   port,
   min(point_count)
from origin_server
```

This gives you the minimum value of point_count for each unique combination of ip and port.

If you want the ip and port with the minimum point_count, try this:

```
select
   ip,
   port,
   point_count
from origin_server
order by 3
limit 1
```

Comment: I just want only one record that has the minimum point_count :)

Comment: OK. See edit to answer for hopefully something more useful. Note that the accepted answer may return multiple rows.

Comment: at first I think that if the situation in my question is incorret, I would use LIMIT, thanks for your answer:)

Comment: Thank me by up voting :) (up-voting means "it's useful")

Answer (score 0):

MIN() function is an agregate function.
So it was correct if your code only return 1 line of result